# Ace Editor PHP Syntax for using brackets

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ace-editor

Trying to figure out how to handle syntax errors when using PHP mode in Ace Editor for shortcodes (to include shortcodes inside of PHP code).  Highlighting already looks/works fine, the problem is with PHP syntax errors showing when shortcodes are used.

A simple shortcode would be `[shortcode]` while an extended one would have open and closing brackets `[shortcode]something[/shortcode]`

```
function foo( $title ) {

    // Example single shortcode (without closing shortcode), [...] will be replaced with "Some value entered by user"
    $site_name = [get_input type="text" desc="Please enter the site name"];

    // Example with open closing shortcodes
    [check_question question="Do you want to add period to the end of the title?"]
        $title .= '.';
    [/check_question]

    $title = ucfirst( $title );

    return $title;
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out how to extend the PHP mode/worker, or what needs to be done to prevent PHP syntax errors from showing in the editor when shortcodes are included?  Everything works great besides the simple PHP syntax errors on shortcodes.

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode

Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tripflex/crm4ywu0/

The regex that is used on backend to replace `[...]` with custom values/code is:

```
\[(\[?)(get_input|check_question)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)
```

Which is direct from WordPress shortcode handling:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/shortcode.js#L105
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L264

Answer (score 0):

You could use that regex to replace brackets at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/mode/php_worker.js#L51, before passing the value to the php lexer.
Unfortunately there is no way to do that without directly modifying the source code in worker-php.js file.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't I be able to extend the PHP mode (creating my own), and then on `createWorker()` define a custom worker or modified worker of some sort?  https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode

Comment: Sorta i guess how is done with Handlebars to support custom curly braces, etc

Comment: you don't need to modify the mode file, the worker file is different